# Anyway to have undertow path template with wildcards

Tags: java, undertow

I need to handle requests that may have a number of sub path elements (that I can ignore), e.g. the following would all map to the same handler:

- /abc?type=a
- /abc/foo?type=a
- /abc/foo/bar?type=a

The only code I have come up with is:

```
Handlers.pathTemplate().add("/{id}", handler).add("/{id}/foo", handler).add("/{id}/foo/bar", handler);
```

But this is not ideal as I need to define each possible path, is there anyway to allow (and ignore) any number of paths following my prefix e.g.

```
Handlers.pathTemplate().add("/{id}*", handler)
```

`Handlers.path().addPrefixPath` allows this sort of matching but then I would lose the path template variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to reference this question. [Routing template format for undertow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911796/2911916)

The accepted answer clearly outlines how to preserve the path variables through **Handlers.routing()**

Comment: I can't check as I am no longer using Undertow or have access to that code but it certainly does look like it would do the job