# Routing template format for undertow

Tags: java, undertow

Is there any documentation about routing template format for undertow. I want to setup handlers like this:

```
/ or /index.html -> Use handler 1
Anything else -> Use handler 2
```

I tried this one, bu did not work:

```
Handlers.routing()
        .add("GET", "/", handler1)
        .add("GET", "/index.html", handler1)
        .add("GET", "/*", handler2)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

**1) Basic approach: `PathHandler`**

```
Handlers.path()
    .addExactPath("/path1", handler1)
    .addPrefixPath("/path2", handler2);
```

The `handler1` will match only on **/path1** (or **/path1/**).

The `handler2` will match on **/path2**, **/path2/** and everything else that starts with **/path2/**.

**2) Route approach: `RoutingHandler`**

If you use a `RoutingHandler`, you have the option to easily extract variables from the paths. That's convenient for building REST APIs for example (note the usage of the convenience `get` method on the `RoutingHandler`).

```
Handlers.routing().get("/{test}/*", exchange -> {
    PathTemplateMatch pathMatch = exchange.getAttachment(PathTemplateMatch.ATTACHMENT_KEY);
    String itemId1 = pathMatch.getParameters().get("test"); // or exchange.getQueryParameters().get("test")
    String itemId2 = pathMatch.getParameters().get("*"); // or exchange.getQueryParameters().get("*")
}))
```

The `*` parameter can match anything (like a path for instance `a/b/c`).
In order to use the `*` parameter, you need an actual named parameter defined before in the route template (`test` in my example).

Note that the parameters defined in your route template will be available together with the query parameters (`exchange.getQueryParameters()`). This is default behavior. If you do not want it, you can create your routing handler like this: `Handlers.routing(false).get(...)` and then retrieve the parameters from the exchange's attachments.

For any route that is not matched by your routing handler, you can use the `fallbackHandler` available in the `RoutingHandler`.

```
Handlers.routing()
      .get("/", handler1)
      .get("/index.html", handler1)
      .setFallbackHandler(handler2);
```

By default the `fallbackHandler` simply returns an empty response body with a 404 status code. The `handler2` will be matching any other requests, not only **GET** requests.

**Comprehensive Example**

You can of course combine `PathHandler` and `RoutingHandler` to fit your needs.

Here is a small example of a more realistic setup:

```
Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
    .setHandler(Handlers.path()

        // REST API path
        .addPrefixPath("/api", Handlers.routing()
            .get("/customers", exchange -> {...})
            .delete("/customers/{customerId}", exchange -> {...})
            .setFallbackHandler(exchange -> {...}))

        // Redirect root path to /static to serve the index.html by default
        .addExactPath("/", Handlers.redirect("/static"))

        // Serve all static files from a folder
        .addPrefixPath("/static", new ResourceHandler(
            new PathResourceManager(Paths.get("/path/to/www/"), 100))
            .setWelcomeFiles("index.html"))

    ).build().start();
```

This application also serves static files from your file system. This is handy to serve a javascript application or static html files for instance.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your answer is correct for my example, but I meant general way to handle wildcard. If we have two `/sample1/*` and `/sample2/*` then single fallback handler does not work.